# Grunt plugins are not installed in current location

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm working with Mac OS X 10.7.5 and I'm using Grunt to concate some js files and minify them. Now I want to also minify my css files. As grunt does not provide any functionality I wanted to install a grunt plugin for that.
According to the instructions i have to cd into my projects root folder and install the plugin with npm. So I did the following:

```
cd <PROJECT_ROOT>
npm install grunt-contrib-css
```

The instructions for the plugin are here: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-mincss
The I opened my grunt.js file and added

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-mincss');
```

But when I try to run grunt I just get

```
Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-mincss" not found. Is it installed?
<WARN> Task "mincss" not found. Use --force to continue. </WARN>
```

The installation works without any problem and npm ls does list the module.

Any ideas what I have done wrong? Many Thanks!

**UPDATED**

When I cd into a project like so

```
cd ~/Sites/path/to/project
```

and then install the plugin

```
sudo npm install grunt-contrib-mincss
```

the module is actually installed in

```
~/node_modules/grunt-contrib-mincss
```

I could hard copy the files into my projects root directory (which works) but it's kind of strange isn't it?

*UPDATE 2*
I've updated node and tried it again. Below is the console output.

```
me:~ Fritz$ node -v
v0.8.10
me:~ Fritz$ npm -v
1.1.62
me:~ Fritz$ mkdir ./Sites/npm-test
me:~ Fritz$ cd ./Sites/npm-test/
me:npm-test Fritz$ sudo npm install grunt-contrib-mincss
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-mincss
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-mincss
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gzip-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-lib
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/gzip-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-lib
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/crc32
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deflate-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deflate-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/crc32
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
grunt-contrib-mincss@0.3.0 ../../node_modules/grunt-contrib-mincss
├── grunt-contrib-lib@0.3.0
├── gzip-js@0.3.1 (crc32@0.2.2, deflate-js@0.2.2)
└── clean-css@0.4.2 (optimist@0.3.4)
```

Why is the plugin installed outside? Or is there a way to define the actual location where it is installed?

Comment: Where is your grunt.js file? Is it in the the same dir that you installed plugin?

Comment: Yes my grunt.js file is in the project root. (Otherwise grunt wouldn't do anything at all, would it?)

Comment: Not necessary it rut folder. You just need to run grunt from the folder there it is places of send path to it in params. I'l try to describe full way to install this plugin that worked for me in answer.

Comment: Well. I have only one idea left. Try to run `npm config edit` in console and look for `global` flag value — it must be set to false. If it is set to true, then the problem probably is in it.

Comment: Looks like its an configuration error, as I get a "file not found" error when I try to open the npms config. Thanks for pointing me into the direction!

Comment: Cool. BTW, you can get value of `global` from console with command `npm get global`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way to install worked for me:

1. `cd <PROJECT_ROOT>`.
2. Run `npm install grunt-contrib-mincss`.
3. Created test file in the current dir with the following testing content:

   ```
   module.exports = function(grunt) {

       grunt.initConfig({
           mincss: {
               compress: {
                   files: {
                       "path/to/output.css": ["path/to/input_one.css", "path/to/input_two.css"]
                   }
               }
           }
       });

       grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-mincss');

       grunt.registerTask('default', 'mincss');

   };
   ```
4. My directory structure looks like this at this moment (please check this, if some files are not there or in some other folder, then it can be reason why it doesn't work):

   ```
   <PROJECT_ROOT> /
       node_modules /
           grunt-contrib-mincss/
       grunt.js
   ```
5. Run `grunt` in terminal.

Script worked.

Possible reasons why it didn't work in your case:

1. You installed plugin globally (with -g argument).
2. You installed it in some subfolder (grunt.js and node_modules must be in the same folder).

Please check it.

Comment: I did exactly the same things. And I figured out that Grunt did not create any node_modules folder. So I tryed installing them globally with -g and hard copied them into the root folder of my project but still when I run grunt it gives me the same errors. And I triple checked the installation, it does not give me any errors or something. I'm kind of confused :D

Comment: What version of node.js and grunt are you using? (Try to update them and install again if they are not the latest ones) Try to clone git repo of plugin to node_modules folder of the project, will it work this way? Also are you install local plugin with sudo command or without it? What right are set on the copied folder?

Comment: I've updated node from 0.8.9 to 0.8.10. I've also updated my question with an output of a test run.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 12.04 for the module `grunt-jasmine-task` (same error message as above). This solved the issue for me:

1. Manually create the folder `node_modules` in the root of the project.
2. Run `npm install grunt-jasmine-task` again.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen cases where not having a `package.json` file present caused the modules to be installed globally. I'm not sure what version was running at the time, as it was not my machine.

Next time try running `npm init` prior to installing modules. After that, install using `npm install grunt-contrib-css --save` to have it added to your `package.json` file. You can also use `--save-dev` to have it added to your devDependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to add:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsdoc-plugin');
```

to grunt.js, so it should look like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    jsdoc : {
      dist : {
        src: ['frontend/js/**/*.js'], 
        dest: 'docs/frontend'
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsdoc-plugin');

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look under the grunt-contrib-mincss folder, there is a readme file, they changed name from grunt-contrib-**mincss** to grunt-contrib-**cssmin**.

anyway, it's not your(and mine) fault. XD